# Create a job that goes through H2O Flow automatically

Tags: apache-spark, h2o, sparkling-water

I have created a flow to predict something with the distributed random forest model and now i want to predict every few days, without using the flow gui.

So is there a way to automate your H2O Flow or to translate the entire script into java/python to automatically run the flow?

Comment: Given your tags, is part of your Flow job involving bringing in data from Spark? Was that just for building the model, or for the prediction part too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using RESTful API to work with H2O backend like the way FLOW works. Based on RESTful API you can create a fully automated solution in a RESTful supported language to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself there is a RestAPI I can use to do everything that i can do in the H2O Flow gui. FYI